# getting full object from select - Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, select

I am trying to get some information by a `select` but I get a `String` and not the whole `Object`

**My code** is the following:

```
<!-- Select Scenario -->
    <div class="form-group bottom">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">{{ 'Scenario' | translate }}</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <select class="form-control" #scenario (change)="getScenario(scenario.value);">
                <option type="text" *ngFor="let scenario of scenarios" >{{scenario.Name}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

but I get as a `value` the `sceanrio.Name` as a `String`.

I **have tried** to change the code for:

```
<option type="text" *ngFor="let scenario of scenarios" value="{{scenario}}">{{scenario.Name}}</option>
```

and

```
<option type="text" *ngFor="let scenario of scenarios" [ngValue]="scenario">{{scenario.Name}}</option>
```

with the aim of getting the object `scenario` as a value, but it does not work (i get `[object Object]`).

My scenario looks like:

```
 export class Scenario {
  Name: String;
  Rec: [{
    recName: String;
  }];
  IntConf: [{
    DName: String;
  }];
}
```

just `Name` is filled at that moment, but I would like to get the whole object (i guess with null in the paraments)

Any idea?

Comment: As a dirty solution, you can use JSON.stringify on options value and then restore it with JSON.parse.

Comment: How does your scenarios object look like?

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Where do you get `[object Object]`?

Answer (score 0):

{{scenario.Name}} is mostly likely has an embedded object. Use a "|json" pipe to confirm like this {{ scenario.Name | json }}

Comment: Please use comment sections for remarks such as these that do not actually answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

To get an actual object binding you should use `[ngvalue]` instead of the plane HTML5 `value`.

Your result should look like this:

```
<option type="text" *ngFor="let scenario of scenarios" [ngvalue]="scenario">
    {{scenario.Name}}
</option>
```

Comment: I have already tried that. It was written in the question but you have deleted it when you have edited

Comment: @MarioLópez oh sorry, I did not delete that on purpose :-/